# Cannot get Cocoa notifications to work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Settting up the observer code:

```
NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self
selector:@selector(updateLog:)
    name:@"Update Log"
  object:nil];
```

Sending the notification code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Update Log" object:self];
```

With the method defined as:

```
-(void)updateLog: (NSNotification *) notification {
NSLog(@"Update Log"); }
```

The text "Update Log" does not appear in the log when the notification is sent.
Thanks for any ideas for why this code is not working.

Comment: I hate to add noise, because I'm not expert on Cocoa on OS X, but are you certain that the shared workspace's notification center is the same as the default notification center?

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between *"the notification center for workspace notifications"* [<sup>Apple</sup>](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-notificationCenter):

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
```

and *"the process’s default notification center"* [<sup>Apple</sup>](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CJBDAAHD):

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

You need to pick one of those to use.